# Editing an oracle table after copying it

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle table with 2 columns, both of them are using NUMBERS data type, When I enter any number starting with 0 it removes the 0. So the solution is to change the data type to VARCHAR2. I have a script that

- creates a temp table with VARCHAR2 and primary key
- copies the old table
- Drops the old table
- Renames the temp to the old table

However I'm facing an issue. When copying the table, any data that was truncated before remains that way, is there anyway I can add a 0 at the start of the old data?. Below is the script I have created.

```
/* create a new table named temp */
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE
(
    IMEISV_PREFIX VARCHAR2(8),
    IMEI_FLAG NUMBER(2),
        CONSTRAINT IMEIV_PK PRIMARY KEY (IMEISV_PREFIX)
);

/* copy everything from the old table to the new temp table */
INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE
SELECT * FROM REF_IMEISV_PREFIX;

/* Delete the original table */
DROP TABLE REF_IMEISV_PREFIX;

/* Rename the temp table to the original table */
RENAME TEMP_TABLE TO REF_IMEISV_PREFIX;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not. When Oracle saves the data to the database, it saves it in the format at that time. All other information is removed. There is no way to restore historic data.

In fact, when you stored the data to the database before, let's say you do this:

```
insert into tableX (anumber) values ('01');
```

In fact it does:

```
insert into tableX (anumber) values (to_number('01'));
```

So it is lost from the very beginning. **(Note that the example is actually a bad habit! You should never rely on casting in the database, always hand over the data in the right data type!)**

Comment: So there is no way I can modify the old data?.

Comment: There is no old data actually.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show that leading zero your problem is a interface problem, not a database problem. You can format your output to show how many leading zero do you want.

If the data is a number let it as is.